# Parsing json in gsp and update the contents

Tags: jquery, json, grails

I have a method in grails controller like this which i am calling from jquery in gsp....

```
def ajaxStatus(){

     CustomerInterest customerInterestInstance=CustomerInterest.get(params.ciId)

     InterestStatus status=InterestStatus.valueOf(params.status)
     customerInterestInstance.status=status

     customerInterestInstance.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)

     render customerInterestInstance as JSON
 }
```

***Question***

> i want to parse customerInterestInstance in gsp and update the content in gsp how can i do
>   this

code i want to update is.....

```
 <span class="staFloat">  
     ${ci?.status}         
         <button onclick="openDialog(${ci?.id})"class=btn id="btn">
            <img id="status_edit"src="${resource(dir:'images/skin',file:'edit.png')}"/>
        </button>
</span>
```

jquery function

```
  "Change": function(){

                  var st = $('[name="st"]:checked').val();


                  $.ajax({
                     url: "${createLink(controller: 'Employee', action: 'ajaxStatus')}",
                      data: ({
                        ciId:ciId,
                        status:st
                          }), 
                      dataType:"JSON",

                success: function(response) { 

                         // call 'refresh' method to load new content

                    alert("changed")  
                       },
               error: function(){
                      alert("Select options");  
                   }

                    });           
                  $(this).dialog('close');
                },
              Cancel : function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
              },
```

Comment: If you want to update the div then you can use `html()` of jQuery. If you want to update the `${ci?.status}` then put this in an span give this span a id then use `html()`.

Comment: i know this but before using html i have to parse json...? right or not?

Comment: You got the json response in your `response` variable in ajax succes there you can easily get any property of `customerInterestInstance` like `response.status`